# Android Input/Rendering: Smooth movement

Tags: android, opengl-es, input-filtering

In my Android OpenGL E.S. 2.0 application, I'm implementing a smooth screen drag feature.
The problem is, that the smoothed movement isn't as smooth as I thought it would be.

Here's some code to start:

```
public class SoftMoveInfo {
    private volatile float mAccumulatedDX = 0.0f;
    private volatile float mAccumulatedDY = 0.0f;
    private final float mSlowDownMult = 0.1f;

    // called by main / input thread
    public void addDragDelta(float dx, float dy) {
        mAccumulatedDX += dx;
        mAccumulatedDY += dy;
    }

    // called by rendering thread
    public void integrate() {
        // adjust movement
        final float moveSubX = mAccumulatedDX*mSlowDownMult;
        final float moveSubY = mAccumulatedDY*mSlowDownMult;
        mAccumulatedDX -= moveSubX;
        mAccumulatedDY -= moveSubY;

        mViewX += moveSubX;
        mViewY += moveSubY;
    }
}
```

`mViewX` and `mViewY` would be the target screen "offset" values, at which the scene would be rendered.
The method `integrate()` is called by the rendering thread and basically advances one movement step.
The method `addDragDelta()` will be called by the rendering thread, which supplies values like so:

```
private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private mSoftDragInfo = new SoftMoveInfo();

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    final int actionMasked = e.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    switch (actionMasked) {
        ...
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            mSoftDragInfo.addDragDelta(x-mLastTouchX, y-mLastTouchY);

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Now the output is really "jittery". Here's an excel graph i made from logging `mAccumulatedDX` during the method `integrate()`:

[image: mAccumulatedDX Output]

As you can see, there are small spikes throughout the graph. I'd like to avoid them.
I have already tried to put all reading and writing events into a `synchronized()` block, but this doesn't seem to help.
I suspect the spikes are due to the fact, that the input thread doesn't supply the information with the same frequency as the rendering thread reads the data.

What may be appropriate techniques to get a smooth movement? I thought about a low-pass filter, but I'm open to better ideas.

Comment: It would help if you defined the scale of this graph. On non-realtime operating systems this sort of jitter comes with the territory, assuming the timescale is small enough. Heck, the Linux kernel (which Android is based on) cannot even keep track of user-mode / kernel-mode thread runtime monotonically; if you were to graph the reported runtime for a thread as it changes scheduled processors you would see what looks like a skewed sawtooth function if you zoomed in far enough :) Long story short, *what timescale are you dealing with here and how are you measuring time in your thread?*

Comment: Thanks, Andon, for your answer. You're right, there is important information missing. Let me provide it now: The method `onTouchEvent()` is called by the android system and specifically the event `ACTION_MOVE` for every detected movement on the screen. So its polling rate heavily depends on how quick a finger moves on the surface and what the maximum polling rate is set in Android. I don't know more about these polling rates.

Comment: The method `integrate()` is called for every `onDrawFrame()` call on a `GLSurfaceView`. Since this is a double-buffered rendering method, it's _usually_ bound to 60 frames per second. However, there are also small spikes, at which the method takes longer to execute (due to a hardware wait for a vsync).
First, I thought the spikes resulted due to the fact that the renderer itself has small spikes. But the thing is: I shouldn't ever get inverse values (smaller when larger expected or vice versa) then. Right?

Comment: Regarding the graph: The vertical scale is simply the raw output of `mAccumulatedDX`. It's value depends on what's left regarding movement deltas (`x-mLastTouchX`). The horizontal scale is rendering frames. It's about 60 fps, but not reliable.

Comment: It's also worth noting that when having done a movement and the finger is about to stop, the spikes are increasing. So I'd say this is because the ACTION_MOVE part isn't called with the same frequency anymore (since less changes are detected).